# How to simulate clicks in a Chrome window via the DevTools Protocol without Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, devtools

I recently made a Chrome auto-clicker using Puppeteer and Electron, but this creates a 40 megabyte executable, which seems like extreme overkill for a simple auto-clicker.

I've spent hours trying to figure out what exactly Puppeteer does to send clicks, but the closest I got was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973617/how-does-puppeteer-handle-the-click-object-devtools-protocol-chromium-chrome) link.

However, it is JavaScript.  My Puppeteer auto-clicker controls an external, pre-installed `chrome.exe`.  So is it sending JavaScript strings to be evaluated by the browser?

I would like to rework [my auto-clicker](https://github.com/GirkovArpa/chrome-clicker) without Node, Puppeteer or Electron, as a standalone executable as opposed to a Chrome extension.

I will probably be using C++ or Pascal but I'm not necessarily asking for code (although that would be nice), but more for how to communicate with whatever API Puppeteer is talking to.

Comment: I might be missing something, but if your extension has access to the DOM content, why not just use the click event on the element? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click If you need in particular x,y positions, you could just inject a proxy element in those positions with an ID you ca nreference in your click.. But it would be much better to know what you've tried.

Comment: Web APIs are unreliable.  Using them to fill out credit card info at `target.com` fails where Puppeteer succeeds, for instance.  So I must use the DevTools Protocol.

Comment: Could be a number of issues, timing issues on the DOM loading, target.com not permitting the use etc. I agree the devtools protocol is better, but if you're building a puchasing sniper, I'm not that that interested to help anymore.

Comment: I am not building a purchasing sniper.  I used my past experience building one as an example of how Puppeteer is more reliable than the Web APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the Chrome Devtools API.

> as a standalone executable as opposed to a Chrome extension

I'm not sure exactly what you mean here, if you mean without the dependancy of chrome, then you're just creating an autoclicker and hoping that the chrome window and URL is the correct one. But that is less about chrome devtools.

As far as I know, the chrome.exe that ships with puppiteer is injected with the extension from puppiteer or selenium for example (but don't quote me on that).

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

Using the API, I would suggest going for the `inspectedWindow` maybe, to execute some JS using the `eval`.

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
          "document.getElementById('someEl').click();",
           function(eventRes, isException) {
             // callback ?
           });
```

Go right from the start though and create a basic extension first.. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

From there you can add your extension to a standalone chrome.exe using the startup command params.

`Path\To\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --load-extension="C:\PAthOfExtension"`

Should get you going.

### Further option

Alternatively or rather some further options.. Would be to package your current autoclicker application including the node and puppiteer into an [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) application which could run as a standalone exe..

Direct to CDP without 3rd Party : 
https://github.com/aslushnikov/getting-started-with-cdp/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I'm using `puppeteer-core` to control my already-installed Chrome.  It doesn't ship Chrome.  
I am familiar with creating Chrome extensions.  I do not want to make an extension.  I want to make a separate program distinct from Chrome.  
My current auto-clicker is already packaged as a standalone Electron application with `electron-builder`.  I want to remake it without using Node, Electron, or Puppeteer.

Comment: @GirkovArpa how do you expect to connect to any chrome instance without it being configured for injection to use CDP ?  In that case, just write any autoclicker and have a listener for the active process. But you wont be able to communicate through the Devtools protocol. by design, it would be incredibly insecure.

Comment: My current auto-clicker [here](https://github.com/GirkovArpa/chrome-clicker) connects to my Chrome and communicates with it via the DevTools Protocol.  How does it do it?  I don't know.  That's why I'm here.  The security (or lack thereof) is not an issue.

Comment: @GirkovArpa so puppiteer will start an instance of chrome.exe with the debug listener open..  `--remote-debugging-port=9222` this allows for communication with DevTools Protocol.

Comment: @GirkovArpa I've update the answer with the resource it sounds like  you're looking for  : https://github.com/aslushnikov/getting-started-with-cdp/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.